# I want to get the url of a ForeignKey in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` of a model with a `ForeignKey`, and I want to return the hyperlink to the instance referenced in that field, but I get the whole object nested in the json.

These are my models:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):

    ONE_STAR = '*'
    TWO_STARS = '**'
    THREE_STARS = '***'
    FOUR_STARS = '****'
    FIVE_STARS = '****'
    GRAND_TOURISM = 'GRAND_TOURISM'
    NA = 'NA'
    SPECIAL = 'SPECIAL'
    ECO = 'ECO'
    BOUTIQUE = 'BOUTIQUE'

    HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (ONE_STAR, _('*')),
        (TWO_STARS, _('**')),
        (THREE_STARS, _('***')),
        (FOUR_STARS, _('****')),
        (FIVE_STARS, _('*****')),
        (GRAND_TOURISM, _('Grand Tourism')),
        (NA, _('NA')),
        (SPECIAL, _('Special')),
        (ECO, _('Eco-Hotel')),
        (BOUTIQUE, _('Boutique-Hotel'))
    )

    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, verbose_name=_('Company'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('Code'))
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='hotels', verbose_name=_('City'))
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HOTEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES, verbose_name=_('Category'))
    capacity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Capacity'))
    position = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, verbose_name=_('Position'))
    in_pickup = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('In pickup?'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Is active?'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Hotel')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Hotels')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Legal name'))
    tax_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Tax ID'))
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('URL'))
    address = models.TextField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Address'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Company')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Companies')

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]{}".format(self.id, self.name)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class HotelProductsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    company = CompanySerializer()
    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_products(self, instance):
        queryset = [product for product in instance.company.products.all()]
        return ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=self.context).data

    class Meta:
        model = models.Hotel
        fields = ('company', 'products')
```

This is my ViewSet:

```
class HotelProductsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Hotel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.HotelProductsSerializer
```

Everything works fine, but the field `company` results in a nested Company object and I would like to get an hyperlink to the object instead.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `company` field is serialized to a nested object because you've declared it with a nested serializer.  Try replacing the line

```
company = CompanySerializer()
```

with something like this

```
company = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    many=False,
    read_only=True
)
```

You may need to adjust the options according to [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined).